# Java Bubble Sort Trouble

Tags: java, runtime, bubble-sort

I've written a bubble sort program that sorts 10000 unique values into order.

I've run the program and it gives me an output of time (using nanoTime) for the time it takes the program to complete, but I wish to add another output to the program's code; How many moves the program takes to sort from start to finish.

Here is the code:

```
public class BubbleSort {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int BubArray[] = new int[]{#here are 10000 integers#};
    System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
        for(int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++){
             System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");
        }

         double timeTaken = bubbleSortTimeTaken(BubArray);
            bubbleSort(BubArray);
            System.out.println("");               
            System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
    System.out.println("    Time taken for Sort : " + timeTaken + " milliseconds.");                
            for(int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++){
                    System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");
        }
}

private static void bubbleSort(int[] BubArray) {

        int z = BubArray.length;
        int temp = 0;

        for(int a = 0; a < z; a++){
                for(int x=1; x < (z-a); x++){

                        if(BubArray[x-1] > BubArray[x]){

                                temp = BubArray[x-1];
                                BubArray[x-1] = BubArray[x];
                                BubArray[x] = temp;

                        }      
                }
        }
}
public static double bubbleSortTimeTaken(int[] BubArray) {
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    bubbleSort(BubArray);
long timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
return timeTaken;
}
}
```

The code executes and outputs how I want it to:

```
Array Before Bubble Sort
13981 6793 2662 10986 733 10107 2850 ... 
Array After Bubble Sort
10 11 17 24 35 53 57 60 61 78 83 89 128 131 138 141 ....
Time taken for Sort : 1.6788472E7 milliseconds.
```

But I wish to add another output to the code where it tells me in how many moves (basically a move counter) it takes to complete, i.e:

```
Time taken for Sort : 1.6788472E7 milliseconds.
Total number of moves: 3000
```

Does this make sense?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Makes sense for what? Why are you interested in such a value?

Comment: Sounds like you need to declare a variable to track the number of moves, and add one (++?) to it whenever the algorithm moves a value. Then you simply have to output that variable at the end.

Comment: By the way, we do you call `bubbleSort(BubArray);` twice? once in `bubbleSortTimeTaken` and once in `main`? If you want to get running time, just remove one calling from `main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change `bubbleSort` to return an int and assign your [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) to it.

```
private static int bubbleSort(int[] BubArray) {

        int z = BubArray.length;
        int temp = 0;

        int itrs = 0;

        for(int a = 0; a < z; a++){
                for(int x=1; x < (z-a); x++){

                        if(BubArray[x-1] > BubArray[x]){

                                temp = BubArray[x-1];
                                BubArray[x-1] = BubArray[x];
                                BubArray[x] = temp;


                        }    

                        itrs++;
                }
        }

        return itrs;
```

}

Then in `main`:

```
int itrs = bubbleSort(BubArray);
            System.out.println("");               
            System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
    System.out.println("    Time taken for Sort : " + timeTaken + " milliseconds.");  
    System.out.println("Time complexity: " + itrs);
```

Comment: "itrs" I'm guessing is the name you're using for Integers?

Comment: an just so I'm clear, the "time complexity" is the number of moves per completion? as in:    Time taken for Sort : 3.8208782E7 milliseconds.
                      Time complexity: 1447551

Comment: Wow, you have helped me out a great deal! I cannot thank you enough. This question has been answered and can now be closed. Thank you foampile!

Comment: you are very welcome.  glad to be of help.  was this homework, BTW?

Comment: That's correct, I was struggling with counting the number of time key operations are performed. I understood how to implement the time for execution, but not for each move. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// returns the number of switches
private int bubbleSort(int[] BubArray) {

        int z = BubArray.length;
        int temp = 0;
        int timesSwitched = 0;
        for(int a = 0; a < z; a++){
                for(int x=1; x < (z-a); x++){

                        if(BubArray[x-1] > BubArray[x]){

                                temp = BubArray[x-1];
                                BubArray[x-1] = BubArray[x];
                                BubArray[x] = temp;
                                timesSwitched++
                        }      
                }
        }
     return timesSwitched;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I appreciate your help and swift response. Although foampile's answer has really sorted my problem out.